# Fading out a led with reed switch loop

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, led

I was hoping to get some help on the fading led which I am working on.

For my project I need to have a led, which when it is placed next to a magnet, continuously shines, but as soon as it is taken away it has to fade out in a certain amount of time. So far I managed to write the code which detects when the light is taken away from the magnet and fades out, but when the magnet is nearby again, the led lights up and keeps shining, no matter  if I take it away from the magnet or not. So how I could solve this? I tried to exit the loop function, but then this process happens only once, which is not what I want. I am also using reed switch to detect the magnet, but if you have other sensor suggestions, let me know. I'm including the code down here.

Thank you for your help in advance:)

```
int ledPin = 9;        
int brightness = 255; 
int fadeAmount = 5;
const int reedPin = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(reedPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  int proximity = digitalRead(reedPin);
  if (proximity == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Switch opened");
    while (brightness >= 0) {
      analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
      brightness = brightness - fadeAmount;
      delay(30);
      Serial.println(brightness);
    }
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Switch closed");
    analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
    Serial.println(brightness);
  }
}
```

Comment: First, please don't provide code as an image. Instead copy and paste the code as text into the question and format it correctly by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button in the question editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem probably comes from the fact, that you execute the fading loop, even if `brightness` is already zero, and that you don't reset it to zero after fading.

```
while(brightness >= 0){
   ...
   brightness = brightness - fadeAmount;
   ...
}
```

Imagine we are at the point, where `brightness` is 5. The while condition is true, since 5 > 0. Then we execute the code in the loop, setting `brightness` to 0. We again check the while condition. It is still true, since `0>=0`. So after executing the code in the loop again, `brightness` is now -5. But `analogWrite()` only takes a 1 byte unsigned (!) integer, aka `uint8_t`, while `int` is a 2 byte signed (!) integer. So only the lower byte of that integer will be used and interpreted as unsigned. So -5 gets interpreted as 251, which you see as lighting up in full brightness.

Easy fix would be to set `brightness` to zero after the while loop:

```
brightness = 0;
```

---

That said, I would suggest a completely different route, which will make your code way more responsive, by using the non-blocking coding principle from the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE.

As you did, I would use a global `brightness` and `fadeAmount` variable, but also one to hold a timestamp:

```
unsigned long timestamp=0;
```

Then in `loop()` we can first do the fading to zero by using the `millis()` function as a clock:

```
if(millis()-timestamp > 30){
    brightness = brightness - fadeAmount;
    if(brightness < 0) brightness = 0;
    timestamp = millis();
}
```

That will decrement the `brightness` variable to zero without blocking with a `delay()`. The speed can be changed by changing the number `30` to something different. This number has the unit milliseconds.

Then we can check for the reed switch and set `brightness` to 255, if it is activated:

```
if(!digitalRead(reedPin)){
    // reedPin is LOW
    brightness = 255;
}
```

So as long as the magnet is at the reed switch, this code will set `brightness` to 255.

And finally we need to write the value of `brightness` to the output pin:

```
analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
```

So as a full code:

```
int ledPin = 9;
int reedPin = 2;

int brightness = 0;
int fadeAmount = 5;
unsigned long timestamp = 0;

void setup(){
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(reedPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop(){
    if(millis()-timestamp > 30){
        brightness = brightness - fadeAmount;
        if(brightness < 0) brightness = 0;
        timestamp = millis();
    }

    if(!digitalRead(reedPin)){
        // reedPin is LOW
        brightness = 255;
    }

    analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
}
```

I've tested this with a normal button (currently no reed switch here). It should work as expected.

Comment: I tested it, it works. Thank you so much!